# simple question on conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

if $ \;G = \langle a,b\;|\; a^9 = b^3 = 1, bab^{-1} = a^4\rangle\; $ of order $\;27\;$

Then how would i show that $b$ is conjugate to $ba^3$

I have been fiddling around with this for ages and cannot come to a conclusion:

I showed that $a^3$ is its own conjugacy class as any power of $a$ and $a^{-1}$ on either side leaves $a^3$ unchanged and by multiplying both sides by $b$ you get $(a^3)^4$ = $a^{12}=a^3$.

Comment: $G\leq a$? What does that even mean? the order or what?

Comment: @ZelosMalum: It means the group $G$ generated by the relations that are written between the matching $<$ and $>$.

Comment: Aha, was so much in there I did not percieve it as being the generation thing, my bad.

Comment: What does being "equivalent" for elements of a group mean? The same order?

Comment: @Timbuc: Equivalent under conjugacy, i.e. belonging to the same conjugacy class: $x$ and $y$ are said equivalent iff $\exists g$ such that $x = g y g^{-1}$.

Comment: @AlexM. How do you know that's what the OP meant? And what you mention is called in group theory "conjugate", as far as I know.

Comment: @AlexM. While that seems clearly the use intended due to the title, I would not say that it is standard terminology in group theory (since we have the term conjugate).

Comment: @timbuc that $x=gyg^-1$

Comment: @Timbuc: Look at the title.

Comment: Good deduction, Alex Holmes...:) . I wonder though how come the OP didn't use **then** "conjugate" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $a^{-1}ba=a^3b$. Then,
$$(ba^{-1})b(ba^{-1})^{-1}=b(a^{-1}ba)b^{-1}=b(a^3b)b^{-1}=ba^3.$$